# Determine if process started via SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, osx-el-capitan

I'm working on a mac and my scripts are interacting with the keychain (codesigning, etc...).  As of El Capitan, interacting with the keychain is very different depending whether a process is started via SSH or locally.  After a process has been started (e.g. in our case, the long running process is the jenkins slave and the various code signing scripts get run via jenkins jobs on top of this process) is there an easy way to determine whether it was started via SSH or Locally?

Ideally some sort of ps -ef | etc... type script?

Comment: FWIW, that particular example is _nearly the opposite_ of "ideal".

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example of something more in line with your definition of "ideal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the output of ps `(ps auwx | grep java)` to see if process associated with the jenkins slave has a controlling terminal. If it does, it was likely started over SSH instead of VNC.

```
USER  PID  %CPU  %MEM  VSZ  RSS  TT  STAT  STARTED  TIME  COMMAND
```

If the TT column is ??, the process doesn't have a controlling terminal. Typically you would see something like "s014" if it was over SSH.

Comment: the `s` in the above 's014' denotes session and then the number, to further check you could check the activity of  said terminal ( if something like screen|tmux is in use this is rather simple to validate.)

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH `sshd` adds several environment variables to the environment for the processes which it starts. You could look for some of the SSH-specific ones:

```
$ ssh localhost
Last login: Fri Sep 16 14:05:49 2016
$ set | grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT='::1 50368 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='::1 50368 ::1 22'
SSH_TTY=/dev/ttys001
$
```

The full list of variables and their meanings are described in [the ssh man page](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh).